# How can "glfw error 65543" be fixed?

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphics, crash

After updating my drivers to the latest version available (nvidia 525.116.04) multiple apps are broken, such as KiTTY and Minecraft. They both have variations on this error:

```
[glfw error 65543]: GLX: Failed to create context: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

Is this an error that I can fix or do I need to reinstall or downgrade my drivers? If it's the latter, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was on the 525 line of drivers instead of 530. Upgrading through the driver manager eliminated the issue.